# running multiple binaries that does not terminate by itself in shell script

Tags: shell

I have several binary in the same folder that I want to run in a sequence.

Each binary does not terminate by itself and is waiting for data from a socket interface. Also, I need to decide whether to run the next binary based on the output of the previous binary. I am thinking of running them in the background and redirect the output of the previous binary to a file and "grep" for the keyword. However, unless I use `wait`, I couldn't capture all the output I want from running the previous binary. But if I use `wait`, I can't get control back because the binary is listening on socket and wouldn't return.

What can I do here?

a sample code here:

```
/home/test_1 & > test_1_log
test_1_id=$!
wait
```

===> I also want to grep "Success" in test_1_log here.
===> can't get here because of wait.

```
/home/test_2 & >test_2_log
test_2_id=$!
wait
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you use sleep instead of wait?

The problem is that you can't wait for it to return, because it won't. At the same time, you have to wait for some output. If you know that "Success" or something will be output, then you can loop until that line appears with a sleep.

```
RC=1
while [ $RC != 0 ]
do
    sleep 1
    grep -q 'Success' test_1_log
    RC=$?
done
```

that also allows you to stop waiting after, say, 10 iterations or something, making sure your script exits